# Prove that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, $g(x)=x$ are unbounded on $(0,\infty)$.

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, bounded-variation

Prove that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, $g(x)=x$ are unbounded on $(0,\infty)$.

We show that $f$ is unbounded by assuming that there is a bound $M>0$ and then arriving at a contradiction.
From the graph of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, it is clear that $f(x)$ is large for values of $x$ which are close to zero. Choose $x>0$ such that $x<\frac{1}{M}$.
Then $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}>M$, and so $M$ is not a bound for the function.
Therefore $f$ has no bound and so is an unbounded function.

I proved the function $f(x)$. The function $g(x)$ also wants to prove similar to that of $f(x)$.
But I don't know what to do.

Comment: If $x>M$ then $x>M$ :)

Comment: contradiction is not necessary for this proof. It's a common first approach, but you should look for a direct proof based on the definitions involved.

Answer (score 1):

Write the definition of boundedness neatly.

Suppose $g$ is bounded on $(0,\infty)$.

Then, there exists $M>0$ s.t. $\bigg[ |g(x)|<M$ for all $x\in (0,\infty) \bigg]$.

Since $|g(x)|<M$ holds for all $x\in (0,\infty)$, $|g(x)|<M$ must hold for $x=M+1\in (0,\infty).$

Then, $|g(M+1)|<M$. Can you lead a contradiction ?